# Read from serial port timeout Windows 7

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I have inherited some software that talks to a device via Serial Com Ports.

It appears to work as expected in an XP environment, but the same code does not work in Windows 7.

Do I need to change something in order to make it work in 7?

Code:

```
Dim ConfigString As String
Dim ConfigSettings() As String
Try
   SerialPort1.Close()
   SerialPort1.PortName = ComPortsList.Text ' Combobox with port in
   SerialPort1.Open()
   SerialPort1.NewLine = vbCrLf
   SerialPort1.WriteLine("RS")
   ConfigString = SerialPort1.ReadLine
   SerialPort1.Close()
   ConfigSettings = Strings.Split(ConfigString, ",")
   SerialNo.Text = ConfigSettings(ConfigSettings.GetUpperBound(0) - 1)
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox("Failed to get serial number" & Environment.NewLine & ex.Message)
   SerialPort1.Close()
End Try
```

All I ever get from this is a timeout error when trying in Windows 7. Works in XP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put a Timer control and read  all the time the serial port
because a device can have a delay to respond.
Inside the timer function verify if there are data to read.
Or check the serial port configuration by default of the device
Like baudrate,stopbits etc. or check in the handbook because some devices doesn't have a menu and make sure you'r are using the same settings in your serial port object.
-Some devices has a command instructions set that sends to the IO ports the value you want to read.

Some of the devices need to end with a VbCrlf char.

I have the same problem when I was trying to read a scale weight in real time.